# Android: StreamProxy not working on Nexus4/5 with Android 5.x

Tags: android, sockets, streaming, audio-streaming

Here is a source of StreamProxy I used for my project

```
public class StreamProxy implements Runnable {
    private static final String LOG_TAG = "Stream proxy: %s";

    private int port = 0;
    private boolean isRunning = true;
    private ServerSocket socket;
    private Thread thread;

    public StreamProxy() {
        init();
        start();
    }

    public int getPort() {
        return port;
    }

    public String getProxyUrl(String uri, String tag) {
        return String.format("http://127.0.0.1:%d/%s", getPort(), uri);
    }

    private void init() {
        try {
            socket = new ServerSocket(port, 0, InetAddress.getByAddress(new byte[]{127, 0, 0, 1}));
            socket.setSoTimeout(5000);
            port = socket.getLocalPort();
            Timber.d(LOG_TAG, "port " + port + " obtained");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Timber.e(e, "Error initializing server");
        }
    }

    private void start() {

        if (socket == null) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("Cannot start proxy; it has not been initialized.");
        }

        thread = new Thread(this);
        thread.start();
    }

    public void stop() {
        isRunning = false;

        if (thread == null) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("Cannot stop proxy; it has not been started.");
        }

        thread.interrupt();
        try {
            thread.join(5000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        Timber.d(LOG_TAG, "running");
        while (isRunning) {
            try {
                Socket client = socket.accept();
                if (client == null) {
                    continue;
                }
                Timber.d(LOG_TAG, "client connected");
                client.setKeepAlive(false);
                readRequest(client);

            } catch (SocketTimeoutException e) {
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Timber.e(e, "Error connecting to client");
            }
        }
        Timber.d(LOG_TAG, "Proxy interrupted. Shutting down.");
    }

    @Nullable
    private void readRequest(Socket client) throws IOException {
        InputStream is;
        String firstLine;
        try {
            is = client.getInputStream();
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
            firstLine = reader.readLine();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Timber.e(LOG_TAG, "Error parsing request", e);
            return;
        }

        if (firstLine == null) {
            Timber.i(LOG_TAG, "Proxy client closed connection without a request.");
            return;
        }

        StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(firstLine);
        st.nextToken();
        String uri = st.nextToken().substring(1);
        Timber.d(LOG_TAG, uri);
        processRequest(client, uri, "");
    }

    @Nullable
    private HttpURLConnection download(String path) throws IOException {
        URL url = new URL(path);
        HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        connection.connect();

        // expect HTTP 200 OK, so we don't mistakenly save error report
        // instead of the file
        if (connection.getResponseCode() != HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
            throw new IOException("Server returned HTTP " + connection.getResponseCode()
                    + " " + connection.getResponseMessage());
        }
        return connection;
    }

    private void processRequest(Socket client, String url, String tag)
            throws IllegalStateException, IOException {

        Timber.d(LOG_TAG, "processing");
        HttpURLConnection realResponse = download(url);
        if (realResponse == null) {
            return;
        }

        InputStream data = realResponse.getInputStream();
        socketWriter.setClient(client);
        try {
            int readBytes;
            Timber.d(LOG_TAG, "writing data to client");
            // Start streaming content.
            byte[] buff = new byte[1024 * 8];
            while (isRunning && (readBytes = data.read(buff)) != -1) {
                client.getOutputStream().write(buff, 0, readBytes)
            }
            Timber.d(LOG_TAG, "end writing data");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Timber.e(e, "Error data transfer to client");
        } finally {
            Timber.d(LOG_TAG, "finally block");
            if (data != null) {
                data.close();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It works perfectly on Android <5.0 but on Android 5.0.+ I have following error with using MediaExtractor(http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaExtractor.html)

```
NuCachedSource2﹕ source returned error -1, 10 retries left
NuCachedSource2﹕ source returned error -1, 9 retries left
...
```

And no error messages when using Mediaplayer just few quiet retries.

Maybe for Android 5 there is another way for audio streaming with caching?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stream proxy working well actually. All errors I get from MediaExtractor was about m4a container. For most files packed in m4a format, there is no way to play it via stream by using components from Android SDK. Except some roms on Samsung, LG and some other manufactures that has this feature.